# How to make the Hazelcast cluster to use only set of ports defined by user

Tags: hazelcast

Here is programming configuration for Hazelcast cluster 
But i am facing some problem here ,its using many random ports other than the defined port ..What will be the issue?

```
   Config config = new Config();
   config.setInstanceName("cluster-1");
   config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
   config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setMulticastGroup("224.2.2.3")
    .setMulticastPort(54327).setMulticastTimeToLive(32).setMulticastTimeoutSeconds(10);
   config.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("192.168.1.23");
   config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
   config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5900);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define outbound port range to be used in your configuration by using the `addOutboundPortDefinition` method of `NetworkConfig` as follows:

```
config.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPortDefinition("35000-35100");
```

For adding single ports to use for outbound network operations, you can use the `addOutboundPort` method of `NetworkConfig` as follows:

```
config.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPort(37000);
```

More info can be found in [Hazelcast reference manual](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#outbound-ports).

Comment: Basically for 3 node cluster how many ports we need to allocate ?
I am facing problem in firewall because i cannot disable the firewall so how how many ports it requires?

Comment: I don't know of any recommendations for the number of ports to allocate. I would experiment with a given number of ports (say 15 for example) and see if everything works correctly.

Comment: I tried with 6 ports but no luck ..i am still facing the problem

Comment: I tried using TCP/IP method iam able to produce the cluster by opening the ports from 37000-37005 But no output for multicast configuration.